# Keyboard usage on macbook air

Tags: macbook-air

I am trying to go to the end of a file in MS Word using a single combination of keystrokes on the macbook air. In windows this can be achieved by using Ctrl Pgdn key combination.

Answer (score 0):

Reference [Word keyboard shortcuts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/mac-word-help/word-keyboard-shortcuts-HA102929541.aspx):

**Moving the cursor**

[image]